# Find success event in SSIS catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, qsqlquery, onerror, ssis-2017

I want this information to add this in a specific table in my database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `SSISDB.catalog.executions`, and `SSISDB.catalog.executables` view for this information:

For the status lookup, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #StatusMap 
CREATE TABLE #StatusMap (StatusId INT PRIMARY KEY, Description varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #StatusMap(StatusId, Description)
VALUES (1,  'created')
, (2, 'running')
, (3, 'canceled')
, (4, 'failed')
, (5, 'pending')
, (6, 'ended unexpectedly')
, (7, 'succeeded')
, (8, 'stopping')
, (9, 'completed')

SELECT sm.Description Result
    , DATEDIFF(Second, e.start_Time, e.end_time) 'Duration (sec)'
    , e.package_name 'Package name'
    , s.executable_name 'Task name'
    , s.package_path 'Execution path'
FROM SSISDB.[catalog].[executions] e
INNER JOIN SSISDB.[catalog].[executables] s on s.execution_id = e.execution_id
INNER JOIN #StatusMap sm on sm.StatusId = e.status
--WHERE e.execution_id = @YourExecutionId
ORDER BY s.executable_id
```